# Finding groups a user is a member where member distinguished name has a comma in it

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap, coldfusion-9

I've got a really simple query that I'm trying to run against Active Directory as an LDAP query.

Its a subtree query and looks like this:
`(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=Moretti\, Stephen,OU=Users,OU=mysection,DC=mydomain,DC=local))`

I've trued a variety of work arounds but because of the \, in the CN of the member DN I don't seem to be able to find the associated groups.

I know that this is the problem, because if I try this with a user with "simple" CN eg : `(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=EasyUserName,OU=Users,OU=mysection,DC=mydomain,DC=local))` I get a list of the groups "EasyUserName" is a member of.

I know that escaping the comma in the CN should work, but it isn't.  I've tried this via a number of different clients including CFLDAP and they fail to return a result set.

Baffled... Anyone seen anything similar?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try escaping the comma according to the [LDAP standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4514) using the hex code for comma.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Sorry for the slow response. I managed to fracture my arm 2 hours after posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not LDAP specific but something I've run into with escaping in various system is that the programming language might be escaping before sending to the server. If this is the situation then escaping the slash might work.

```
cn=last\\, first
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been in similar situation and escaping it like that works.  Have you checked that it's not because of other things?  Have you verified the member's DN?  Should there be a space after the comma?

Have you tried other tools like LDP to query AD?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up the user & then get the groups they're a member of (attribute is memberof).

Comment: This is a work around that I had made for this specific issue, but needed to get a solution for searching for for dn for forthcoming functionality. thank you though.